# Collect Form Data Posted from Any Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms

Say I create a static .html page. Next I build a form with a bunch of input boxes. Then I decide I want to post all that form data to another page, call it process-form-data.aspx. My question is, since I posted the form data to an .aspx page, how can I use C# in the code behind screen to grab all that data?

I tried the following first:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
string valTextBox1;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtBox1"]))
{
     valTextBox1 = nvc["txtBox1"];
     Response.Write(valTextBox1);
}
```

And then I tried:

```
valTextBox1 = Request.Form["txtBox1"].ToString();
Response.Write(valTextBox1);
```

But neither method seems to work. I can only get those two methods to work if I submit the form using the runat="server" attribute on an .apsx page.

I'd like to avoid passing the variables through the URL.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Was `txtBox1` the name of the HTML input field that you posted?

Comment: If you don't want to use GET then use POST.

Comment: @Brandon Yeah, the name attribute was set to name="txtBox1".

Comment: `string = valTextBox1;` is not valid c# - it should be `string variableName = valTextBox1;` or just `string valTextBox1;`

Comment: @Chriseyre2000 Such a dumb mistake. Thank you. I thought the form defaulted to POST, but I just set the the attribute to method="post" and it worked fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @Robbie Good eye. Somehow that got messed up when I brought it over from my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions! I thought when a form was submitted, the default method was to POST the data; turns out it's GET. (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

I just added the following attribute to the form tag: method="post".

```
<form action="process-form-data.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txtBox1" />
</form>
```

Both methods of collecting the form data mentioned in the original post work fine.